# Play Framework overide db username and password in Java

Tags: java, database, playframework, database-connection

Is it possible to update the db username and password present in application.conf file of Play Framework (2.5.8) on load of application in Java?

Other words where exactly (Java Class) in play framework the db username and password is read from application.conf file to connect database.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with: Other words where exactly in play framework the db username and password is read for connecting database.

Comment: its present in application.conf file. Some java class should be there to read it and use it for db connection. I want to know that java class